# How to read the first N bytes of a file or less if it is shorter?

Tags: rust

Is there an easy way to read the first N bytes of a file in Rust? The two most relevant functions seem to be [`read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read) and [`read_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact), but `read` can return fewer bytes than available for whatever reason, so I would have to call it in an annoying loop, and `read_exact` gives up if the file is shorter than N bytes (whereas I'd prefer it to just read the entire file).

This is not a duplicate of this question which can be solved with `read_exact`: [How to read a specific number of bytes from a stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412521/how-to-read-a-specific-number-of-bytes-from-a-stream)

Comment: I would guess not, due to it trying to encapsulate all of the functionality of C's read function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042287/read-from-regular-file-block-or-return-less-data

Comment: `reader.take(N).read_to_end()`

Comment: Is that efficient? I feel like there's a decent chance it might do stuff one byte at a time...

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that question because - as I explained in the question - I want to read fewer bytes if EOF is reached. The linked question is about reading exactly N bytes and failing if you get EOF first. I think this was pretty clear in my description but I edited the title to make the distinction clearer. Please reopen!

Comment: The `.take(N).read_to_end()` solution is inefficient: [it only reads 32 bytes at a time until the last read where it reads whatever remains to reach the total](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#2285-2290) instead of attempting to read `N` bytes at once.

Comment: @Jmb that sounds like it would be better as a comment on the answer that suggests using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just going to copy the `read_exact` implementation and modify it slightly. It was already really close to working as desired.

```
/// This is the same as read_exact, except if it reaches EOF it doesn't return
/// an error, and it returns the number of bytes read.
fn read_up_to(file: &mut impl std::io::Read, mut buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, std::io::Error> {
    let buf_len = buf.len();

    while !buf.is_empty() {
        match file.read(buf) {
            Ok(0) => break,
            Ok(n) => {
                let tmp = buf;
                buf = &mut tmp[n..];
            }
            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::Interrupted => {}
            Err(e) => return Err(e),
        }
    }
    Ok(buf_len - buf.len())
}
```

(Completely untested!)

Comment: I think you linked `read_to_end`? [`read_exact`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2113659479a82ea69633b23ef710b58ab127755e/src/libstd/io/mod.rs#L764) unless I am being stupid!

Comment: Yes, sorry about that!

Comment: @Stargateur: No. Read my question and the `read()` documentation. I think I was pretty clear.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Why? The correct answer to the "duplicate" is `read_exact()`.

Comment: @Timmmm  _so I would have to call it in an annoying loop_ This is stated in your question but this answer has also loop, would you like to reconsider the answer on dupe? I thought you were looking for more idiomatic or concise solution?

Comment: Yeah my answer is not ideal. The `.take(N).read_to_end()` solution is definitely more convenient but I don't want to sacrifice performance so I'm going to use this inconvenient solution.